# Possession in English

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, possessives, apostrophe

Which is the subject and the verb in the following sentence?

> This Beach's beauty is startling.

I'm reading a book of English grammar and I need to underline the subject and verb.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work.

Comment: Since none likes to do homework, and certainly not other people's homework, we can help you best if you try this one yourself, and let us know why you are lost.

Comment: "Beauty" is the subject, "is" is the verb.

Answer (score 1):

This Beach’s beauty: SUBJECT  is: AUXILIARY VERB